# How do I perform multiple extrusions around a spiral?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I managed to select the same edges on most of the objects using select>select similar by face angles. Is it possible now to extrude all of them straight outwards from themselves?

[[image: [1]]

Comment: Would you like to extrude them all in [this manner](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LX8mA.gif) ? (shown only for one mesh in the gif). I think scaling along normals (`Alt`+`S`) doesn't suit your needs because it makes all the individual parts become larger ?

Comment: would like to extrude straight outwards so it looks like the thing has legs like a millipede

Comment: I think [Alt]+[E] or [E] > [Alt]+[S] should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an array modifier to make a millipede, that way you don't have to mold all of the legs individually, but just once.

starting with a spiral (I used the AddCurve:Extra Objects add-on)

[image]

[image]

then create the base object:

[image]

Add an array modifier, set the fit type to Fit Curve and select the spiral as the curve object:

[image]

Add a Curve modifier and select the spiral as the object.

[image]

Select a few opposing faces on your face object and do Extrude Individual.
To shape the legs.

[image][image]

When you exit edit mode you should get something similar to this.

[image]

You could also add a new object to be used as the head

[image]

and select it to be used as the end of the array (maybe you could use a tail object as well, I don't know anything about entomology..)

[image]

The beauty of working with modifiers is that you can go back and edit the main object and reedit as much as you want and all of the instances on the array will be modifies as well. If you edit the spiral curve then all of the array will follow.

[image]

[image]

Adding an empty and using it as object offset on the Array modifier will allow you to scale it so the back of it is larger than the front.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks great. is there a way to make the sections progressively larger? and a way to skew the curve?

Comment: The curve can be any shape  you want. See updated answer for scaling

Comment: excellent thankyou. I made mine in Groboto will have another go in Blender

Answer (score 0):

Select everything in edit mode, P (Seperate), by loose parts.
Then in object mode, select all the loose objects, and with one of them selected as the Active object, Control-L and link the mesh data.
Then go into edit mode and on one of them, scale outwards on Bounding box centre or such with the relevant edges selected. All of the other meshes should follow suit automatically.