# Scale a mesh cylinder instanced to geometry node grid

Tags: scale, geometry-nodes

B"H With 2.93 trying to form an audio visualizer with mesh cylinders instanced to all vertices on geometry node grid. Looked in Manual 2.93/Blender stack exchange/multiple tutorials. Geometry Nodes were initially formed with mesh circle. Deleted geometry node input.  Added geometry-grid, point instance and mesh cylinder. With point instance node, selected cylinder.
How to decrease scale so cylinders not overlap?  When scaled down the cylinder in 3d viewport, the size of the instanced cylinders is not altered.  Then tried multiple variations of geometry node combinations (including transform node before and/or after pt instance; object info node scale connected to point instance....) without any change in size of instanced cylinders.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just scale down your cylinder in Edit mode, then all instances will be scaled.

Another option: Use the point scale node before the Point Instance node. Otherwise, it scales the points in the instances.
This has the same effect.

Comment: Maybe add: the _Point Scale_ node *before* the _Point Instance_ node. Otherwise, it scales the points in the instances. ( I've only just discovered you can nest Point Instancing.. you can instance more objects on the vertices of instanced objects )

Comment: thank you! added!

Comment: B"H Chris and Robin, Sequentially tried to scale 1st mesh cylinder then instanced cylinders in Edit Mode.   Will try again Thank you!  Also thank you very much the prompt response!    It worked. 0.361  THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If my answer helped, please check the checkmark legato my answer. Thank you!