# How to create razor wire

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I am trying to create fences with razor wires on them, as to be seen here: 
[image]

I modeled it as a straight wire first, adding the blades in an array and then combined the cylinder and the blades to one object. But when I try to deform it with the screw modifier it get's too distorted. I also didn't get any usable results by trying to start off with a coil already and using particles, for example.

If anyone has an idea to solve this, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks for reading. [image]

Comment: What you've tried to do is not very clear, what do you mean by "combined the cylinder and the blades to one object"? Array along a spiral curve seems to be the good solution

Comment: Model a single segment of the wire and razor. Create a curve object with the spiral shape you need (use the Add Curve: Extra Objects addon to create spirals) Add an array modifier to the wire/razor object and then add a curve modifier that uses the spiraled curve as object for the array. Something like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/how-do-i-perform-multiple-extrusions-around-a-spiral/45445#45445

Comment: When I try it as you recommend with your link I don't get any usable result, just a row of array, that doesn't follow the path at all. And @moonboots I meant I joined them using ctrl+J.

Comment: you need two modifiers: array and curve, and have the curve modifier use the curve object. Please show an image of what you get and how the modifiers are set.

Answer (score 2):

Model a single segment of the wire and razor.

[image]

Create a curve object with the spiral shape you need (use the Add Curve: Extra Objects addon to create spirals)

[image]

Add an array modifier to the wire/razor object

[image]

and then add a curve modifier that uses the spiraled curve as object for the array. Then set the array modifier to use the curve.

[image]

The original object and the curve remain editable, so you can shape them to fit your needs.

Here's the example file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems to solve:

1. To distribute the barbs evenly along the length of the curve
2. To do so without distorting the barbs

This used to be a typical use for Dupliframes, but they has been removed from 2.8.. they apparently don't play well with the new dependency graph.

so you can treat the barbs as particles (which will not be distorted), and distribute their *emitter* evenly along the curve. Distortion of the emitter will not be inherited.

- Create a plane to be an emitter for the barbs
- Give the emitter-plane  Array and Curve modifiers, both along its Z, to distribute instances of it along the curve
- Give the plane a particle system with the barb as target object.. particle settings something like the illustration below:

[image]

(Lifetime: as long as you like .. Count: the count of the plane's array modifier, the Barb object edited to have its local X along the curve)

Result: (plane yellow, barb blue, curve red)..

[image]

.. which has the advantage that you can put a random twist on to the barbs, if you want to, using the 'Phase' settings in the particle system's 'Rotation' panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a curve modifier after your screw modifier.

First align a curve on top of you wire.

[image]

Then add a curve modifier and set the curve to the one you just created.

[image]

Even I'm not very good with curve modifiers and find them to be a bit finicky at times. It is important to make sure you apply rotation and scale for the curve and the the wire because sometimes they can lead to some weird results. In my experience, it usually works better to have the curve's and the wire's origins on the same spot too.

And I can never guess which is the correct deformation axis either. Just go through them all until you find the one that works. In this example, I also had to move the wire a little bit so the curve would have more of an affect. Be sure you do that carefully and only on one axis at a time so you don't mess anything up.